# Made a JSON file with multiple objects with a simple template

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a template JSON file used by REST API POST request. This file contains this object

```
{
    "Subject": "template",
    "Body": {
        "ContentType": "HTML",
        "Content": "template"
    },
    "Start": {
        "DateTime": "2014-02-02T18:00:00",
        "TimeZone": "Europe/Paris"
    },
    "End": {
        "DateTime": "2014-02-02T19:00:00",
        "TimeZone": "Europe/Paris"
    }
}
```

I wrote a little function to change some datas inside this object and save this into another json file called `jsonOutput.json`

There is the function to change datas, this is working well.

```
function insertDatasJson (res) {
    let fs = require('fs');
    let base = require('../public/json/template.json');

    base.Subject = 'f';
    base.Body.Content = 'e';
    base.Start.DateTime = '2016-11-13T08:30:00';
    base.End.DateTime = '2016-11-13T17:30:00';

    fs.writeFileSync('./public/json/output/jsonOutput.json', JSON.stringify(base, null, 4));
}
```

Now I trying to do the same modifications but I have a lot of datas to modify (multiple Subject, multiple Content and multiple Start/End dates)

I trying to have an output file like this

```
[
    {
        "Subject": "1",
        "Body": {
            "ContentType": "HTML",
            "Content": "1"
        },
        "Start": {
            "DateTime": "2014-02-02T18:00:00",
            "TimeZone": "Europe/Paris"
        },
        "End": {
            "DateTime": "2014-02-02T19:00:00",
            "TimeZone": "Europe/Paris"
        }
    },
    // some other objects ...
    {
        "Subject": "n",
        "Body": {
            "ContentType": "HTML",
            "Content": "n"
        },
        "Start": {
            "DateTime": "2014-02-02T18:00:00",
            "TimeZone": "Europe/Paris"
        },
        "End": {
            "DateTime": "2014-02-02T19:00:00",
            "TimeZone": "Europe/Paris"
        }
    }
]
```

The problem is, if I do a simple loop in my little function, every data will overwrite the one before and I will get an output file like the template.

How can I make to not overwrite datas during the loop and to have an output file like my example ?

Comment: Are you asking how to not overwrite the file you write out to?

Comment: are you trying to append the jsonOutput.json file?

Comment: That would result in invalid JSON. If you want several objects in a JSON file you need to create an Array and push the objects into that created array.

Comment: yes i'm trying to append the jsonOutput.json file

Comment: see clurect's answer

Comment: @DevDig Why do you believe that valid JSON is a requirement here? Or why do you think that Array is necessary for storing multiple JSON objects in a file?

Comment: I agree with @DevDig too, I overlooked that problem. JSON should have a single root element. An array or an object works. But if it is not required to be valid then by all means go ahead

Comment: @freakish If it is not valid JSON, its some JavaScript object in a file, not JSON

Comment: @DevDig It does not have to be a valid JSON. As long as it serves OP's purposes.

Comment: @freakish OK, was confused because the files are names .json and the OP talks of 'json file', but you are right

Comment: Yes my bad I failed when I wrote the example I want. I really want JSON but I forget the main array, I will edit my post

Comment: A bit off topic, but if you need it, the `jq --slurp` command with that option can help you convert a file that contains a list of data like the former example, but is not proper JSON, as when it is stored in an array delimited with commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are writing all data at once, then you need to do create an array, push all objects to array and write the array to file

```
function insertDatasJson (res) {
    let fs = require('fs');
    let base = require('../public/json/template.json');
    let result = [];
    for (/*you loop statmeent*/) {
      let obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(base));  // or your preferred way of deep copying
      obj.Subject = 'f';
      obj.Body.Content = 'e';
      obj.Start.DateTime = '2016-11-13T08:30:00';
      obj.End.DateTime = '2016-11-13T17:30:00';
      result.push(obj);
    }

    fs.writeFileSync('./public/json/output/jsonOutput.json', JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
}
```

Or if you want to write data in multiple runs, then

```
function insertDatasJson (res) {
    let fs = require('fs');
    let base = require('../public/json/template.json');
    let data = require('./public/json/output/jsonOutput.json');
    base.Subject = 'f';
    base.Body.Content = 'e';
    base.Start.DateTime = '2016-11-13T08:30:00';
    base.End.DateTime = '2016-11-13T17:30:00';
    data.push(base);
    fs.writeFileSync('./public/json/output/jsonOutput.json', JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
}
```

However, in second case, you need to add some code to handle the case of first run when there is no existing data in the output file, or file doesn't exist. Another way to handle that condition would be to initialize the output file with empty JSON array

```
[]
```

EDIT: In both cases, appending to the existing file will not work as it will generate invalid JSON.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem is that you are overwriting the file with `fs.writeFileSync()`.

You should use `fs.appendFileSync()` to add new data to the end of the file. See the node docs.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_file_data_options

Answer (score 1):

The plain truth is that you should use a database like MONGODB if you really have many of these objects to save. Anyway here is my solution your way:

you JSON file should hold an array not an object, in your function use push 
Somethink like this (did not try to run this, just get the idea):

coode:

```
function insertDatasJson (res) {
    let fs = require('fs');
    let base = require('../public/json/template.json');

    let base2={};
    base2.Subject = 'f';
    base2.Body.Content = 'e';
    base2.Start.DateTime = '2016-11-13T08:30:00';
    base2.End.DateTime = '2016-11-13T17:30:00';
    base.push(base2 );

    fs.writeFileSync('./public/json/output/jsonOutput.json', JSON.stringify(base, null, 4));
}
```

JSON:

```
[];
```

Comment: And why do you believe it should?

Comment: because U can push any number of objects into an array.This way U read the file push new objects a rewrite it back

Comment: No, I'm asking why do you believe that a file should hold an array instead of appended JSON objects? Were did the OP said that he wants that? Not to mention that your solution is very inefficient: you have to keep **all** objects in memory. Streaming is impossible.

Comment: @freakish See here http://www.json.org/, JSON can only hold one Object or an Array

Comment: @freakish I do not know it it's a huge file that he needs.It's a good simple and practical solution for up to a few hundred objects. True not good for millions of objects, this will require a database like MONGO anyway